# Not receiving dropdown of custom autocomplete textfield

Tags: forms, javascript, routes, 9

I am currently trying to create a postcode lookup which returns a street name in an autocomplete dropdown.

To do this I have created a new module  containing the following files:

- src/Controller/AutocompleteTestController.php
- src/Form/AutocompleteTestForm.php
- js/autocomplete.js
- my_module.info.yml
- my_module.routing.yml
- my_module.libraries.yml

*AutocompleteTestController:*

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\autocomplete_test_v1\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Drupal\Component\Utility\Xss;

/**
 * Defines a route controller for watches autocomplete form elements.
 */
class AutocompleteTestController extends ControllerBase {


  /**
   * Handler for autocomplete request.
   */
  public function get(Request $request) {
    $results = [];
    $input = $request->query->get('q');

    // Get the typed string from the URL, if it exists.
    if (!$input) {
      return new JsonResponse($results);
    }

    $input = Xss::filter($input);

    $input = $this->getLatLong($input);

    $results[] = [$input];

    return new JsonResponse($results);
  }

  public function getLatLong($postcode){
    $gmapsAPI = 'hidden';
    $query = "https://maps.google.co.uk/maps/api/geocode/json?components=postal_code:" . urlencode($postcode) . "&output=json&key=".$gmapsAPI;
    $data = file_get_contents($query);

    if($data){
        $data = json_decode($data);
        $street = $data->results[0]->formatted_address;
        return array('Street' => $street);
    }else{
        return false;
    }
  }
}
```

*AutocompleteTestForm:*

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\autocomplete_test_v1\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Render\Element\Textfield;

/**
 * Form to handle article autocomplete.
 */
class AutocompleteTestForm extends FormBase {


  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getFormId()
  {
    return 'autocomplete_test_v1_form';
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form['address'] = [
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => $this->t('Autocomplete address'),
      '#autocomplete_route_name' => 'autocomplete_test_v1.addresses',
      '#autocomplete_route_parameters' => [],
      '#process' => [
        [Textfield::class, 'processAutocomplete'],
      ],
      '#attributes' => [
        'autocomplete' => 'off',
      ],
      '#attached' => [
        'library'  => [
            'autocomplete_test_v1/autocomplete'
        ],
      ],
    ];

    return $form;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    // Extracts the entity ID from the autocompletion result.
    $address_v1 = $form_state->getValue('address');
  }
}
```

*my_module.routing.yml:*

```
autocomplete_test_v1.addresses:
  path: '/autocomplete_test_v1/autocomplete'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\autocomplete_test_v1\Controller\AutocompleteTestController::get'
    _format: json
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'

autocomplete_test_v1.autocomplete_test_v1_form:
  path: '/admin/autocomplete_test_v1/autocomplete/form'
  defaults:
    _form: 'Drupal\autocomplete_test_v1\Form\AutocompleteTestForm'
    _title: 'Automcomplete Test'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

*Autocomplete.js:*

```
(function ($) {
    Drupal.behaviors.autocomplete.attach = function attach(context) {
      var $autocomplete = $(context).find('input.form-autocomplete,textfield.form-autocomplete').once('autocomplete');
      if ($autocomplete.length) {
        var blacklist = $autocomplete.attr('data-autocomplete-first-character-blacklist');
        $.extend(Drupal.autocomplete.options, {
          firstCharacterBlacklist: blacklist || ''
        });
  
        $autocomplete.autocomplete(Drupal.autocomplete.options).each(function () {
          $(this).data('ui-autocomplete')._renderItem = Drupal.autocomplete.options.renderItem;
        });
  
        $autocomplete.on('compositionstart.autocomplete', function () {
          Drupal.autocomplete.options.isComposing = true;
        });
        $autocomplete.on('compositionend.autocomplete', function () {
          Drupal.autocomplete.options.isComposing = false;
        });
      }
    };
  })(jQuery);
```

**Problem**
My main problem is that the dropdown does not appear properly (A thin empty bar). A response is generated however.

Any tips or help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

**Solution** 
 For anyone who comes across a similar error; the problem lay within the controller. 
 So the results I was generating as `$input` was an array in which I was embedding into another array of `$results[]`.

**Code Changes**
Change this:

```
$input = $this->getLatLong($input);

$results[] = [$input];
```

To this:

```
$results[] = $this->getLatLong($input);
```

Make sure that your key values are either defined in #autocomplete_route_parameters as well.